# What happens at small claims court if two parties present differing copies of a contact?

Tags: united-states, contract-law, england-and-wales, fraud, digital-forensics

For example this actually happened to me. Psycho landlord prints out unusually drafted lease agreement and send to me as PDF. I read it and am in fact perfectly happy to sign it because it appears to reflect our agreement as discussed and in good faith.

I print it in duplicate but neither of the copies are stapled.

Digitally sent copy is no longer accessible as we both changed phones.

We both sign the final/signature page of each copy and she takes her copy's signature page, but leaves the rest of her copy and the whole of my copy with me saying she just needs the signature anyway.

Then let's say I'm illegally evicted and need to prove my tenancy in local county court. The pages are all loose and she goes to court with a contract that says completely different things which she has happened to collate with the other loose signature page. We each claim the other person's version of the "signed" contract is fraudulent. How is this adjudicated?

Comment: This is why I like to initial each page, even when I'm not required to.

Comment: Great idea @brhans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### It’s judged on the evidence

You give your version, she gives hers, any other witnesses give theirs. The court then decides who they believe.

Comment: What if there are no witnesses, and it is quite literally merely my word against hers?

Comment: @JosephP. See above.

Comment: Yes, but the very question is *how* the court decides what to believe!

Comment: @JosephP. No. That’s not the question you asked. Feel free to ask that question.

Comment: no offense, but the question itself makes no mention of witnesses, and then literally says "how is this adjudicated?"

Comment: @JosephP. Documents don’t just get put into evidence magically- they have to be testified to by a witness. Again, ask another question if you want. Questions are free.

Comment: I assume that you meant independent third parties by witnesses.

Comment: @JosephP. Why would you assume that. The plaintiff and defendant are both witnesses if they testify (and if the plaintiff doesn’t they don’t have a chance of winning.

Comment: I see. I thought that plaintiffs and defendants are referred to respectively even when testifying rather than as witnesses, which I'd thought implied third parties that witnessed relevant events such as the signing of the contract. As parties of the dispute I would naturally think of them more as participants in the events they would be testifying as to, rather than witnesses.